# Two disks showing contents unknown and unable to format or partition

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, disk-formatting

I recently added a new internal hard disk to my setup and now my two other data drives are suddenly showing as 'Contents Unknown' in the disks application with no option to mount them. I assume it would be odd for these two drives to completely fail at exactly the same time.

In the Disks application, I can see these two disks, however they do not show up in gparted.

None of the data on these two disks is critical so I am fine if the data is lost. However, I am unable to format the disk or format the partition in the Disks application. When trying to format one of the disks with 'Don't overwrite existing data (quick)' option and 'GPT' option, I get this error:
**Error wiping device: Failed to probe the device '/dev/sdc' (udisks-error-quark, 0)**

When trying to format partition with erase disabled and with 'Ext4' option (without password protect volume (LUKS) option), I get the same error as above:  **Error wiping device: Failed to probe the device '/dev/sdc' (udisks-error-quark, 0)**

Output from `sudo fdisk -lu /dev/sdb`
`fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Input/output error`

Is there a way to determine if these drives can be fixed or if they are destined for the scrap heap?

Comment: Hm check the cables maybe you detach something hard drives showing up in bios or uefi?

Answer (score 1):

Per [nobody](https://askubuntu.com/users/966203/nobody) I checked all of the cables and connections again. I also noticed one power cable was using an adapter to connect to three drives while the other power cable was connected to only one drive. I removed the adapter and now each power cable is connected to two drives.

I am now able to access the drives and the data so everything is good to go.

Going forward, I will use the results from `fdisk -1` to determine if drive is fully connected as opposed to the Disks application.